# Ubuntu - How to run a terminal command on boot?

Tags: ubuntu

I want to execute a command when Ubuntu boots. The commands in particular are:

```
sudo shutdown +m
sudo shutdown +1
```

I want the computer to shut down as soon as it starts for testing purposes. I plan on switching the computer back on with a bit of circuitry I am testing.

How can I execute this command automatically at system start up?

Comment: "auto shutdown at boot" sounds evil. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Place it in `/etc/rc.local`. (It is run as root, so `sudo` is not needed there.)

Also, you may be interested to read additional info about runlevels: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel

Comment: You can also go to System/Preferences/Startup Applications, and add the script there.

Comment: Not working for me on Ubuntu Server 18.04 - I want to swap on as `sudo swapon /swapfile`

Comment: Use crontab with @reboot syntax working for me ref. https://superuser.com/a/586078/34893

Answer (score 5):

There are different ways to automatically run commands:

1. The [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) system will execute all scripts form which it finds a configuration in directory `/etc/init`.  These scripts will run during system startup (or in response to certain events, e.g., a shutdown request) and so are the place to run commands that do not interact with the user; all servers are started using this mechanism.  You can find a readable introduction to at: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html the man pages `man 5 init` and `man 8 init` give you the full details.
2. A shell script named `.gnomerc` in your home directory is automatically sourced each time you log in to a GNOME session.  You can put arbitrary commands in there; environment variables that you set in this script will be seen by any program that you run in your session.  Note that the session does not start until the `.gnomerc` script is finished; therefore, if you want to autostart some long-running program, you need to append `&` to the program invocation, in order to detach it from the running shell.
3. The menu option *System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications* allows you to define what applications should be started when your graphical session starts (Ubuntu predefines quite some), and add or remove them to your taste.  This has almost the same purpose and scope of the `.gnomerc` script, except you don't need to know `sh` syntax (but neither can you use any `sh` programming construct).

Answer (score 1):

For simple things you can add a command in *System->Preferences->Sessions* pointing to the location of your script.

Alternatively you can add it to `/etc/init.d/rc.local` or make an [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) job if it's a more *low level* stuff.

Take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto for more info