# How to run a script at boot time for normal user?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I want to run a bash script at boot time in CentOS 6. I added the script in `/etc/init.d/` directory but all these script are run by root. I want to run script for any user.

Answer (score 8):

You can add it to your crontab like this:

```
@reboot /bin/bash /dir/of/your/script
```

If you are not familiar with `crontab`, here you have some hints:

- `crontab -l` lists current jobs scheduled.
- `crontab -e` allows you to edit it.

Comment: i know how to edit crontab but when  i edit using crontab  -e it will create file for current user to /var/spool/cron/ if i have this line added in rpm package then it will create cron file for root because for installation purpose i have to login as root.

Comment: You can use `crontab -u <user>` (and `crontab -l/-e -u <user>`) to set up crontab for other users.

Comment: awesome sir!!! this is the easiest way to autorun startup scripts. I had researched but all of them told that we need to config /etc/init.d/*** bla bla... to complicated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Running scripts at boot time is very dangerous for the system security. Therefore here is a good reason for root-only scripts. So, if you **have** root access - use it (you're an sysadmin, right?), if you haven't access - it is probably better for you leave it as it is.. :)

If your question is about how to change the effective UID for some rc.d script, you can use something like:

```
#!/bin/bash    

export MYHOME=/path/to/somewhere

case $1 in
    start)   /bin/su <username> $MYHOME/bin/startup.sh ;;
    stop)    /bin/su <username> $MYHOME/bin/shutdown.sh ;;
    restart)
             /bin/su <username> $MYHOME/bin/shutdown.sh
             /bin/su <username> $MYHOME/bin/startup.sh
             ;;
esac
exit 0
```

so, you can put your script anywhere and from the init-script will run it with `su`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `su` to drop root privileges by using the `-c` to run a command, like:

```
# su user -c whoami
  user
```

If you want a specific script to drop privileges, then you can just call the script itself with `su <user> -c <script> -magic-parameter` where `-magic-parameter` tells the script to do what ever you want it to do as a non-root user.